# Is there a way to generate a lookup table using XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to generate a lookup table using XSL given an xml file.

I have a data set that changes periodically, I need to use this data as a lookup table in another XSL (2.0) script. I currently have the lookup table hard coded in my XSL script but since the data changes, its a pain the behind updating the script.

I want to generate this lookup table as an external file and refer to it from my other script.

the xml with the data that is used to generate the lookup table looks like this:

```
<doc>
    <BO>
        <RTS>
            <Code>001</Code>
            <Val>74</Val>
        </RTS>
        <RTS>
            <Code>002</Code>
            <Val>111</Val>
        </RTS>
   <!-- Lots more -->
   <BO>
<doc>
```

The current lookup table (that is imbedded) looks like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="lookup" >
        <row Code="001"   Val="74"/>
        <row Code="002"   Val="111"/>
        <!-- Lots more -->
</xsl:variable>
```

I am not sure if the external file lookup table needs to be in a different format(?). As long as I can generate the lookup table and be able to use it from my current script is fine.

Edit:
just to clarify, (I'm new to XSL) I am looking for guidance of how to use the input xml as a lookup table in my XSL.

Comment: So what exactly is your question? You can easily use an external XML file as your "lookup table" provided you pass the path to the file as parameter to your XSLT stylesheet and point the key() function to the external document.

Comment: @michael.hor257k 
Your question prompted me to rethink how I worded this question and my approach to the problem. Thank you. I am going to delete this post, rethink my approach and possibly repost a new question.

Comment: Now you tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am looking for guidance of how to use the input xml as a lookup table in my XSL.

You did not post your XSL or your XML input. Consider the following example, based - loosely - on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72637842/using-lookup-tables-in-xsl-to-find-corresponding-values):

**XML**

```
<input>
    <object>
        <code>002</code>
    </object>
    <object>
        <code>001</code>
    </object>
</input>
```

**lookup.xml**

```
<doc>
    <BO>
        <RTS>
            <Code>001</Code>
            <Val>74</Val>
        </RTS>
        <RTS>
            <Code>002</Code>
            <Val>111</Val>
        </RTS>
        <!-- Lots more -->
    </BO>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="lookup-path">lookup.xml</xsl:param>

<xsl:key name="lookup" match="RTS" use="Code"/>
  
<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="object">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="code"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('lookup', code, document($lookup-path))/Val"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<input>
   <object>
      <code>002</code>
      <Val>111</Val>
   </object>
   <object>
      <code>001</code>
      <Val>74</Val>
   </object>
</input>
```

Comment: Wow, this is great. I was going to rethink this but this is exactly what I had in mind! I was using the hard coded lookup table but wanted to use that xml to create a lookup table. Your first comment prompted me to rethink and use the xml as the lookup table. You nailed it Thank you!